# cannot access elements of a list with f string

Tags: python, list, arraylist, face-recognition

trying to iterate list of images in a folder  starting with [0] element
but getting list index out of range error

........................code...........................

```
KNOWN_FACES_DIR = "known_faces"
UNKNOWN_FACES_DIR = "unknown_faces"

for name in os.listdir(KNOWN_FACES_DIR):
    for filename in os.listdir(f"{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}"):
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f"{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}/{filename}")
        encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
        known_faces.append(encoding)
        known_names.append(name)
```

........................error..............................

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
C:\Users\KURO\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject1\python.exe C:/Users/KURO/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py
loading known faces
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KURO\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: thats because list is empty

Comment: You're accessing an index in the list that's empty.

Comment: problem is hidden inside image loading code. you probably expect face_encoding to have elements so first find out why it has none

Comment: sorry iam  a newbie, but i do have 4 images in that ```known_faces``` folder

Comment: Yes, it seems that there are a number of files, otherwise the `for` loop would not run. Since it does, then there is a problem with one of those files. It seems that `face_recognition.face_encodings(image)` returns an empty list.

Comment: but wont the ```image``` in the ```face_recognition.face_encodings(image)``` gets files from ```known_faces``` from  the code line above it